# Regular Expression to find pipes in double quote fields and replace them

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regular expressions so i am struggling

I need to find pipes with in double quotes and replace them for the below string

```
"040436529|abc|xyz|is omg"
```

should turn to

```
"040436529 abc xyz is omg"
```

I'm using this regex : `(\")(.)+?(?:\"\||[\r\n])`

```
1174176|||"gmarathon7@yahoo.com"||9|"00000000000111"||"Ywvdgimkkm"||"Zmstwll"||"101 Ross Rd"|||"Kennebunk"|"PE"|"040436529|abc|xyz|is 
 omg"|"20130329"|"19541130"|"207"|"2513566"|"207"|"2513566"|||0|4703|"N"||"20150508"||"20180904"|"201809"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

str = "040436529|abc|xyz|is omg";

replaced = re.sub("\|", " ", str);

print replaced
```

Output:

```
040436529 abc xyz is omg
```

Comment: That would replace other pipes as well, the ones not in double quotes

Comment: Oh ok, I'm not sure you can solve this with regex. It would be hard to ignore middle '|' in : `"in|quote"out|of|quote"back|in|quote"`

Comment: \|(?=(?:(?!\").)*(?:\"\||[\r\n])) this worked for me